# How to handle word in the middle using "look ahead" and "look behind" in Regex?

Tags: regex

From answer of @skyfoot at this question
[regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups)

He said that:

```
given the string `foobarbarfoo`

    bar(?=bar)     finds the first bar.
    bar(?!bar)     finds the second bar.
    (?<=foo)bar    finds the first bar.
    (?<!foo)bar    finds the second bar.

you can also combine them

    (?<=foo)bar(?=bar)    finds the first bar.
```

What's happened suppose i have string "`barfoobarbarfoo`"

And i want to find these bold text

"bar**foo**bar**bar**foo"

The regex might be: `(?<=bar)foo(????)bar(?=foo)`

The question is that what expression should be in the middle (`look ahead` or `look behide`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this pattern

```
foo(?=bar)|(?<=bar)bar
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/156)

Answer (score 1):

To complete your example:

```
bar(?=bar)     finds the `bar` followed by `bar`
bar(?!bar)     finds the `bar` NOT followed by `bar`
(?<=foo)bar    finds the `bar` preceeded by `foo`
(?<!foo)bar    finds the `bar` NOT preceeded by `foo`
```

So, in your case, you want the `foo` preceeded by `bar` **AND** followed by `bar`. Using the example above, this should give:

`(?<=bar)foo(?=bar)`

Then, to find the `bar` preceeded by `bar` **AND** followed by `foo` you should use:

`(?<=bar)bar(?=foo)`

Finally, to combine those two patterns, you should use the **OR** operator and you end up with the following:

```
(?<=bar)foo(?=bar)|(?<=bar)bar(?=foo)
```

<kbd>[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lD6oB3/1)</kbd>

Comment: I started anwsering before you accept the other answer xD ... I'll leave it though if more exaplanations are needed ;-)